# Find all urls with a query string in them

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I have a list of URLS that look like this:

```
http://example.com/php?id=2
https://example.com/?
http://example.com/ip/admin/navigate?
http://example.com/admin?page=2&id=3
https://www.google.com/#q=query
```

What I need to do is scan these URLS for a query string and only output that ones that contain that query. For example, the expected output would be:

```
http://example.com/php?id=2
http://example.com/admin?page=2&id=3
```

I came up with the idea to do this:

```
res = []

with open('textfile.txt', 'a+') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        if '?' in line:
            res.append(line)
return res
```

However, this will grab everything that has a `?` in it including this URL: `https://example.com/?` is there a way I can grab all the links with a query string in them avoiding the ones with just a question mark?

Comment: Why are you using `a+` mode for a file you're only reading? The mode should be `r`.

Comment: @Barmar just an example

Comment: @User9123 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
import re

query_regex = re.compile("(.*)[?|#](.*){1}\=(.*)")
urls = """http://example.com/php?id=2
https://example.com/?
http://example.com/ip/admin/navigate?
http://example.com/admin?page=2&id=3
https://www.google.com/#q=query""".split("\n")

for url in urls:
    match = query_regex.match(url)
    if match:
        print(match.group())
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to check if the question mark is in the string, but not as the last char:

```
res = []

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        if '?' in line and not line.endswith('?'):
            res.append(line)
return res
```

You can also use regex or other solutions, I think this is the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would lead to erroneous solutions but you could also test for = signs

```
res = []

with open('textfile.txt', 'a+') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        if '=' in line:
            res.append(line)
return res
```